# Google Code SVN reset

Tags: svn

I have accidentally reset my Google Code SVN, and now my /trunk and /branches folder are gone, so I cannot commit anything due to my URL no longer existing. How can I reset the SVN to its default setup with the commit folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step1**
You simply create the folder `trunk`, `tags` and `branches`, add the folders and check them in. There is nothing special with those folders except for the name.

**Step2**
Setup a working backup...